# Transparent png not showing bg image just bg color in html

Tags: html, css, png, transparency, background-color

I have a logo that is a transparent png and i want to overlay it on my bg image but when i do it shows only the background color.

Here is an example:
[image: failed transparency]

I am using a modified copy of the WP theme Colourise
The Css is here: http://files01.s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/colourise/style.css
And the page here: http://s0urc3.ismywebsite.com/index.php

Comment: IE has problems with PNGs. Which browser(s) did you use?

Comment: Firefox and the webkit engine in Coda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this rule on line 87 of the CSS:

```
img {
    background: #1B1B1B;
    border: 1px solid #1B1B1B;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It's applying a background color to every image. You'll need to override this for the logo or remove it entirely.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOO.....MUCH MAN i have been so busy with school that i haven't had time to sort it out.

Comment: @ellis Tip: Use a decent browser such as Chrome or Safari or Firefox with Firebug installed. Right-click any element and choose *Inspect Element*. There'll be a list of all the styles that apply to the element and information where it came from. It's that simple.

Comment: I used to have firebug but it was killing my computer :P
I have an OLD iBook G4

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem as well. After all the Googling I just needed to click around a bit on SO.